# Can't commit in Emacs 29.0.50 , magit 20220412

Tags: magit

I'm running `emacs` version 29.0.50, with the most recent `magit` and since yesterday I've not been able to create (or amend) a single commit.

```
*ERROR*: Not inside Git repository
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/run/user/1000/emacs/server445850'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

This used to work fairly well up until recently, and now failing almost every single time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to running git off of an NTFS volume. Previously git didn't care much about the file system. Now it does, so running `magit` on the repository produces an error message which `magit` neither handles nor forwards in an understandable to the reader fashion.

To anyone having this problem in the future; just move the repository to a proper file system which supports UNIX ownership and permissions, e.g. `ext3`, `ext4`, `btrfs`, `zfs` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Version 29.0.50 is the version used by the unreleased master branch of Emacs. You appear to be using a prerelease version of Emacs, which you either recompile yourself from time to time or which you download from some other source from time to time. You should examine the most recent update to see which commits could have caused the regression, then send an email to the Emacs development mailing list with that information. They should be able to fix the regression once they know about it, even if you cannot.

The variable `emacs-repository-version` holds the git commit hash from which your current Emacs was built. Of course you will need similar information about the previous build of Emacs that you were using.

Of course it is possible that you haven’t updated Emacs at all, despite appearances. Perhaps you updated git or magit instead, and the problem is related to that. Figure out what changed yesterday and add that information to your question.