# Unable to commit in Magit in a repo on an NTFS filesystem

Tags: magit

My situation is similar to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71376/cant-commit-in-emacs-29-0-50-magit-20220412): I have a git repository on an NTFS volume mounted on Linux (Ubuntu). Using Magit I am able to see status, stage and unstage, but committing doesn't work and the magit-process buffer shows `*ERROR*: Not inside Git repository`.

That person's solution was to move the repository to another filesystem, but that isn't an option for me and I'd like to understand more about why this isn't working. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/876908/985093) (not magit related) suggests that errors are caused by the way files are written and suggests the command `git config core.filemode false`, but this didn't work for me.

To focus this question on Magit (as this is an Emacs site!), what I am basically asking is: what magit command triggers this, and why does it not happen using the native Git CLI? For instance `magit-process` shows that the command that errors out is:

```
git --no-pager --literal-pathspecs -c core.preloadindex\=true -c log.showSignature\=false -c color.ui\=false -c color.diff\=false commit --
```

But when I run this is in a shell, it works fine. So how is `magit-commit` different?

Comment: Is this truly under Linux or is this WSL?

Comment: Real Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS)